# Are CAs allowed to modify CSRs before signing?

Tags: digital-certificate, pki, certificate-authority, csr

Can anyone please tell me if Certifying Authorities (CAs) are allowed to make modifications to the Certificate Signing Request (CSR) before actually signing the certificate with their own private key?

Specifically, I'd like to know if it's valid for the CA to insert additional fields (such as EKUs) into the cert before adding their signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

The Certificate Authority is responsible for enforcing the organisations PKI security policy via its policy files and templates. This may include EKU (extended key usage) attributes.

In reality you are requesting a certificate of a certain type from the CA on behalf of your subject. It is up to the CA to enforce the type of certificates (and the associated uses) that it will issue.

The CA is not actually modifying the request so much as issuing a cert of a permitted type.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak about CAs in general, but I once ran a Windows Server 2003 network with its own CA, and it's definitely possible to make `certreq` (through the `-attrib` option) add additional fields to the CSR before it gets to the CA. Thus, it looks to me like it's possible for the CA itself to do much the same thing.

Your mileage may vary.